# Error inflating class com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView in a Native App

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I am trying to plot a line graph of sensor values.I added the Graphview library and add to the path .
But when i run my code i get this error

```
01-23 22:13:03.142 11400-11400/DvrApp.Framework E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: DvrApp.Framework, PID: 11400
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{DvrApp.Framework/com.DvrApp.activity.Mainactivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:851)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:667)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
        at com.DvrApp.activity.Mainactivity.onCreate(Mainactivity.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:851) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:667) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
        at com.DvrApp.activity.Mainactivity.onCreate(Mainactivity.java:54) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:851) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:667) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat
        at com.jjoe64.graphview.Viewport.<init>(Viewport.java:433)
        at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.init(GraphView.java:207)
        at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.<init>(GraphView.java:180)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
        at com.DvrApp.activity.Mainactivity.onCreate(Mainactivity.java:54) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:851) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:667) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: it would have great if you post up java and xml code

Comment: here is the one of the solution to your problem --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025180/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-9-error-inflating-class-co

Comment: <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:id="@+id/line_graph"/> @Wini